# How to change the colour of a header bar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am creating a simple `TicTacToe` game and first I created a splash screen. I have easily managed to change the header bar color to orange by simply using `activity_splash_screen.xml`.

[image]

Then I created my homepage called `activity_home.xml`. And when I click on the bar there it doesn't get active and thus does not allow me to change the colour from blue to orange. Could you please explain to me how this can be fixed

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write this code Inside OnCreateView: getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity ,R.color.my_statusbar_color)
getWindow()..clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

Comment: You mean Toolbar color?

Comment: apply the theme of splash screen to your home screen also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For staging Status bar colour user the below code in your Activity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        int colorCodeDark = Color.parseColor("#FF9800");
        window.setStatusBarColor(colorCodeDark);
    }
```

For changing Toolbar colour set background for Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

Comment: The only thing I had to do in addition to  your instructions to make it work was to "Change app theme style to noActionBar" just as Kartik Shah suggested

Answer (score 6):

In your styles.xml in your AppTheme **`android:colorPrimary`** property is responsible for toolbar color change this to your color.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
<!-- Main theme colors -->
<!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
<!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

or apply below property to your toolbar

```
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to change in manifest where you have declared the activity .
Change app theme style to noActionBar.
Now come to your main activity and initialize the new toolbar and set the color in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the header bar color in styles.xml file...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">write color code(#000000)</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">write color code(#000000)</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">write color code(#000000)</item>
    </style>
```